# Add Item to Sherlock Action Bar

Tags: android

[image: Custom Image]

I want to cutomize sherlock action bar like below with one changes [image: image2]

when user click on icon1 it show a dropdownmenu like image2.

or how to add three imageview in action bar in image2 to the roght side of small dropdow icon.

I am following the shrelockaction bar sample code but not able to find it how to do that?

Comment: Refer to this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: but i want to it programatically

Comment: Open that link.  They have done it programmatic-ally. What do you think Google is and does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following,

```
    public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
    setupBackActionBar();
}


protected void setupBackActionBar()
{
    final ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(     
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.LEFT );
    titleBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.actionbar, null );
    titleActionbar = ( TextView ) titleBarView.findViewById( R.id.acb_title_text );

    titleActionbar.setText( "Your title" );

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled( false );
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled( false );
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled( false );
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled( true );

    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView( titleBarView, layoutParams );

}
```

And create your own view for actionbar like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/acb_title_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks i get an idea from your code and now i am able to do it.